# Macbook's "Internal Memory Card Reader" uses 896ma/900ma doing nothing, is this normal?

Tags: macbook-pro, power-management

One a new mid-2014 macbook pro:

```
Internal Memory Card Reader:

  Product ID:   0x8406
  Vendor ID:    0x05ac  (Apple Inc.)
  Version:  8.20
  Serial Number:    000000000820
  Speed:    Up to 5 Gb/sec
  Manufacturer: Apple
  Location ID:  0x15400000 / 21
  Current Available (mA):   900
  Current Required (mA):    896
  Built-In: Yes
```

This is what System Report reports, there is no card in the reader, is this normal?

Comment: are you sure it is using that? Available and Required don't strike me as the same as currently using...

Comment: of course I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: but I get the point, is it more of an allocation / estimation metric then?

Comment: That is my guess, but maybe someone who knows for sure will answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Required lists what is necessary to operate the device (the internal memory card reader) *not* what is being used.

[This Apple Support article](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT4049) is about USB ports, but the information under **Confirming power usage in System Profiler** is directly applicable to your question. In this case the "port" over which power requirements are noted is where the internal card reader is connected to the motherboard, not the card reader itself.